# create new variables with a for cycle

Tags: php, arrays, variables, element, variable-assignment

Hi I have a list of values named:

- $value1
- $value2
- $value3
- ...

and I'd like to assign each value to an array element; something like:

```
$my_array[1]=$value1;
$my_array[2]=$value2;
$my_array[3]=$value3;
```

How can I do this using a for cycle? The array is not a problem but I can't figure out how to write some code for the value, it should be something like:

```
for($i=1; $i<=10000; $i++)
{
    $my_array[$i]=$value$i;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=10000; $i++) {
    $val_name = "value" . $i;
    $my_array[$i]=$$val_name;
}
```

Comment: If you're wondering, it's called [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Thanks everyones! It works but I should use just one $ instead of two, so  $my_array[$i]=$val_name;

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

```
for($i=1; $i<=10000; $i++)
{
    $my_array[$i] = $value;
}
```

Or this, if you want to append the counter as well:

```
for($i=1; $i<=10000; $i++)
{
    $my_array[$i] = $value . $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are the {}.

```
$my_array[$i]=${'value'.$i};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1; isset(${"value$i"}); $i++) {
  $my_array[$i] = ${"value$i"};
}
```

This syntax is known as [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$$` syntax:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
    $name = 'value' . $i;
    $my_array[$i] = $$name;
}
```